# How to remove padding from rows on mobile devices in bootstrap 4.5?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4.5 in my project, i would use an edge to edge view when the website is opened on a mobile device.

I have a layout as the following

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-9>...</div>
     <div class="col-md-3>...</div>
</div>
```

So when it's on a desktop it looks fine but on mobile there is too many padding and i would make the content looks like edge to edge

[image]

i've tryed to use `no-gutters` on `row` and to remove padding from container but it makes the desktop version look bad..

Comment: That padding must be coming from `container`. Please use media-query to reduce the padding from container class.

Comment: @SunnyVaghadia that's how i solved the problem, you can check my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the problem by writing my own media-queryes as the following:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) { // setting default row and cols values for non mobile screens
  .row {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
}

  .row [class*='col']{
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
  }

}

.row {  // setting rows margin and cols padding to 0 for mobile screens
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.row [class*='col']{
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

And by adding this to container class `class="container px-0 px-sm-3"`

Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
<div class="container mx-0 mx-sm-3">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-9">...</div>
     <div class="col-md-3">...</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

---

`mx-0` sets the container margin to 0 on the x-axis and then `mx-sm-3` sets it back to 3 (1rem) for small and up (sm, md, lg, and xl)

[Spacing in Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/)

Comment: container contains padding and not margin. I doubt this code will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can either write your own media-query for this or use the spacing classes provided by bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

`class="p-0"` == `padding: 0 !important;`

Answer (score 0):

You can add in your html a class named p-sm-0 and p-0
or you can add a media query just for mobile and add to container class in css padding: 0